# Insert parent and children records

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child

I have 2 tables a parent called emp_infoand a child called emp_attendance, which are connected by empid.

Currently, I am using 2 different sequences, one for each table to create the empid.  For the emp_attendance table I create a record which has null values than I do insert or update with random date time fields. Ses code below.

I would like to get rid of the sequence emp_attendance_seq and the MERGE code and do either nested inserts or use the empid from the emp_info table to populate the emp_attendance table.

Can you provide the workaround to my request.

Drop sequence emp_info_seq;
Drop table emp_info;
Drop sequence 
    emp_attendance_seq;
Drop table emp_attendance;

```
Create sequence  emp_info_seq;


CREATE TABLE emp_info(
   empid INTEGER,
 empname VARCHAR2(50)
);



INSERT INTO  emp_info 
SELECT emp_info_seq.NEXTVAL,
DBMS_RANDOM.string('U', 
  DBMS_RANDOM.value(3,15))
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY  LEVEL  <=3;



Create sequence
emp_attendance_seq;




CREATE TABLE  emp_attendance    
(empid INTEGER,
 start_date DATE,
 end_date DATE );



INSERT INTO  emp_attendance
(empid)
SELECT
emp_attendance_seq.NEXTVAL
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY  LEVEL  <= 3   ;

MERGE INTO  emp_attendance  dst
USING  (
           WITH    cntr (n)  AS
           (
               SELECT  LEVEL  AS n
               FROM    dual
               CONNECT BY  LEVEL <=5

       )
       ,    got_start_date (rid, empid, start_date)   AS
       (
           SELECT  CASE
                       WHEN  cntr.n  = 1
                       THEN  e.ROWID
                   END
    ,       e.empid
           ,       trunc(sysdate)
                       + dbms_random.value (1, 30)
           FROM    emp_attendance  e
           CROSS JOIN              cntr
           WHERE   e.start_date  IS NULL
       )
       SELECT  rid
       ,       empid
       ,       start_date
       ,       start_date + dbms_random.value (0, .75)  AS end_date
       FROM    got_start_date
   )  src
ON  (dst.ROWID  = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET  dst.start_date = src.start_date
    ,    dst.end_date   = src.end_date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN.   
INSERT (dst.empid, dst.start_date, dst.end_date)
       VALUES (src.empid,  src.start_date, src.end_date)
;
```

/

```
EMPID    START_DATE     END_DATE
1    20200603 20:06:47    20200603 21:51:02
1    20200611 08:07:12    20200611 20:34:13
1    20200614 10:24:01    20200614 17:16:12
2    20200616 04:50:04    20200616 19:08:22
2    20200608 19:39:52    20200608 21:01:01
2    20200613 00:56:53    20200613 08:23:10
3    20200615 13:46:58    20200616 01:30:50
3    20200621 03:15:32    20200621 07:54:38
3    20200613 04:13:58    20200613 06:38:28
```

Comment: What is your question?  I don't follow what you are asking.  Sample data and desired results *as text tables* are a big help.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered similiar question somewhere, but can't find it. My suggestion is to use `insert all`. Example below generates 3 rows in first table and 5 rows for each of them in child table:

```
insert all 
  when rn = 1 then into emp_info (empid, empname) values (id, name)
  when  1 = 1 then into emp_attendance (empid, start_date, end_date) 
                   values (id, d1, d1 + dbms_random.value (0, .75))
select ceil(level/5) id,
       case mod(level, 5) when 1 then 1 end rn, 
       dbms_random.string('U', dbms_random.value(3, 15)) name, 
       trunc(sysdate) + dbms_random.value (1, 30) d1
  from dual connect by level <= 3 * 5
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c793e4c164c3071480fec64b6f617362)</sup>**

---

**Edit**: I will try to explain best as I can, so step by step. This is our main query, which generates 15 rows containing random data:

```
select ceil(level/5) id,
       case mod(level, 5) when 1 then 1 end rn, 
       dbms_random.string('U', dbms_random.value(3, 15)) name, 
       trunc(sysdate) + dbms_random.value (1, 30) d1
  from dual connect by level <= 3 * 5
```

- `ceil(level/5)` changes id, so 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 becomes '1', values 6-10 becomes 10.
- `case mod(level, 5) when 1 then 1 end rn` prepares value which decides if this row will be put to `emp_info`, only first row of each five is marked with `1`
- `connect by level <= 3 * 5` is responsible for generating 15 rows

Next we have conditional `insert all` which allows us to put row into only first table or both tables:

```
insert all 
  when rn = 1 then into emp_info (empid, empname) values (id, name)
  when  1 = 1 then into emp_attendance (empid, start_date, end_date) 
                  values (id, d1, d1 + dbms_random.value (0, .75))
```

I also added this part `with max(id) + level` to allow further uses of this `insert`. Please read about hierarchical queries and conditional insert, practice and everything will be clear.

Comment: Dbfiddle spot on !! Thanks for your help. If I run this code more then once I see the emp_info numbers start from the number 1 again and not max(empid+1) would that be an easy change to make. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Find max id and add it to level in connect-by query: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b40a6f02cd14fe2e1c15aae5ad650d59).

Comment: I know I need to do this SELECT NVL(MAX(id), 0) AS MAX_VAL FROM emp_info but should it be added to the ID column? Why the level? Can you please explain and place in the code. Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: I constructed IDs as simple integers. Level is used similarly like in your `cntr` subquery. It starts from 1, so if table already contains data we have to add max ID to level. This solution is good to make quickly big set of random data, but not good in real environment, where concurent sessions could produce duplicates. Standard approach is triggers and sequences or autogenerated columns in newer Oracle versions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of the code I fully understand it all except for your comment about max(id) + LEVEL. Will that increase the number of iterations of loop?

Comment: Nope. It is our starting point for next pack. When last used Id was 700 we have to start from 701. 700 will come from max(id) plus 1 from level (then 2, 3, 4..). You can change number of iterations where I hardcoded values 5 and 3. 3 is number of rows in main table, 5 is number of child rows for each main row.

Comment: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here  when I add the max function un the level line. So I tried adding the max function in other places and I got syntax errors. Do I need a subquery?

Comment: In my last dbfiddle I showed you one option, with the `WITH` clause usage. It is called CTE (common table expression). You can do it also with subquery. Both possibilities in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4c4c33ad14e84658bbaa83f14043271).